# Calling a PHP script from within PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that I'd like to run both via the browser and from the command line. When I run the script from the command line, it executes without a problem. However, when I call it via a function such as `exec` or `passthru`, it doesn't work. I'm not getting any output from the call and I see no errors in the logs. I'm very confused...

```
echo exec('php /usr/share/nginx/www/function.php arg1');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you may need to provide the path for php, if you logged the output you would see any errors returned

Comment: I'll try adding the full path for PHP...

Comment: I added the full path to PHP - still does nothing and returns nothing...

Comment: Also, I gave everything 777 permissions just to rule permissions out... (by everything I mean everything under www)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is captured in a parameter variable as an array and not returned back, when you use `exec()`. So do something like this:

```
exec('php /usr/share/nginx/www/function.php arg1', $output);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried this and the result is `Array()`.

Comment: What does your script do? does it print anything into stdout? what are these logs? are they created by function.php?

Answer (score 0):

@David,

A few things to check.

1. Create a PHP Info  page and see if exec or passthru is enabled. Hosts disable it for security.

Try:

```
<?php

$exe = exec('php /usr/share/nginx/www/function.php arg1');

var_dump($exe);

?>
```

You could even do:

```
<?php

if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
}
?>
```

Comment: I ran this test - exec is indeed enabled.